# How to get row count from all tables of a schema ( without using information schema )

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.6, count, information-schema

The query should collect data from table name , schema name from information.schema and row count should be taken from actual table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is actually a very good question since MyISAM stores the count in its header, whereas InnoDB requires a full count (See my answer to the post [Why doesn't InnoDB store the row count?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/17926/why-doesnt-innodb-store-the-row-count/17992#17992))

## SOLUTION

Use [**INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES**](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/tables-table.html) to create the SQL for counting each table

#### ALL DATABASES

```
SET group_concat_max_len = 1048576;
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT('SELECT ',QUOTE(db),' table_schema,',QUOTE(tb),
' table_name,COUNT(1) table_rows FROM `',db,'`.`',tb,'`') SEPARATOR ' UNION ')
INTO @CountSQL
FROM (SELECT table_schema db,table_name tb FROM information_schema.tables WHERE
table_schema NOT IN ('information_schema','performance_schema','mysql')) A;
SELECT @CountSQL\G
PREPARE s FROM @CountSQL; EXECUTE s; DEALLOCATE PREPARE s;
```

#### CURRENT DATABASE

```
SET group_concat_max_len = 1048576;
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT('SELECT ',QUOTE(db),' table_schema,',QUOTE(tb),
' table_name,COUNT(1) table_rows FROM `',db,'`.`',tb,'`') SEPARATOR ' UNION ')
INTO @CountSQL
FROM (SELECT table_schema db,table_name tb FROM information_schema.tables WHERE
table_schema = DATABASE()) A;
SELECT @CountSQL\G
PREPARE s FROM @CountSQL; EXECUTE s; DEALLOCATE PREPARE s;
```

#### SPECIFIC DATABASE (like `mydata`)

```
SET group_concat_max_len = 1048576;
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT('SELECT ',QUOTE(db),' table_schema,',QUOTE(tb),
' table_name,COUNT(1) table_rows FROM `',db,'`.`',tb,'`') SEPARATOR ' UNION ')
INTO @CountSQL
FROM (SELECT table_schema db,table_name tb FROM information_schema.tables WHERE
table_schema = 'mydata') A;
SELECT @CountSQL\G
PREPARE s FROM @CountSQL; EXECUTE s; DEALLOCATE PREPARE s;
```

To see the SQL that is generated run this

```
SELECT @CountSQL\G
```

## GIVE IT A TRY !!!

See docs at https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/tables-table.html